# How create a symfony form type for tags with select2 v4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, jquery-select2-4

Im trying to update an already-created form type (`TagsType`) from select2 v3 to v4. But I found the problem that the new select2 use selects instead of text field. The following code works fine with v3.

```
class TagsType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addViewTransformer(new StringToArrayTransformer());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $attr = isset($view->vars['attr']) ? $view->vars['attr'] : [];

        $view->vars['attr'] = array_merge($attr, ['data-toggle' => 'tags']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }
}
```

StringToArrayTransformer:

```
class StringToArrayTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function transform($value)
    {
        if (!$value ) {
            return [];
        }

        if (!is_array($value)) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected a Array.');
        }

        return implode(',', $value);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            return [];
        }

        if (!is_string($value)) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected a String.');
        }

        return explode(',', $value);
    }
}
```

The above code works fine with a Entity with field of type `simple_array` (comma separated). I need do the same but using the new vesion of select2.

Refactoring:

```
class TagsType extends AbstractType
{

   /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $attr = isset($view->vars['attr']) ? $view->vars['attr'] : [];

        $view->vars['attr'] = array_merge($attr, ['data-toggle' => 'tags']);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(['multiple' => true]);
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }
}
```

The refactor generate a select tag with multiple but empty. And when try to add some option (`Tag`) the validation fails because dynamic creation of new options in the select.

My questions:

- How to implement a choice with dynamic options in symfony?
- How to set default choices from field data (array)

Comment: update your twig template for that type of form

Comment: that does not solve the problem, the validation continue failing because all dynamic options added to the select through javascript, and how get default options (choices) from the current field data (array) ?

Answer (score 0):

Forget all about ',' and convert string to array or vice versa and save each Tag entity individually.

So, to make your form compatible with select2-v4.x you need one EntityType field with 'multiple' attribute set to TRUE.

Every thing is handled by symfony, each option(s) in select tag of your form is connected to its entity.

I just found this solution and it works for me, but I don't know maybe some things are missing...

Comment: Yes but this way you need to have the tags already existing

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I found it from Search engine. I tried to make it with simple_array + data transformer — it's wrong way (as @YaserKH said). Better to make tags as entity Tag etc. (you can find in the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)). But if you need simple solution for some reasons (as me):

1. Create Text type column in database (not simple_array)
2. Define it as HiddenType in form builder:

```
    $builder->add('tagsForSearch', HiddenType::class, [ 'required' => false ])
```

3. Make twig like:

```
    {{ form_row(form.tagsForSearch) }}
    <select id="tags" multiple="multiple">
        {% for tag in form.tagsForSearch.vars.value|split(',')|default %}
            <option value="{{ tag|raw }}" selected="selected">{{ tag|raw }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

4. And script:

```
$('#tags').select2({
    tags: true
});
$('#form').submit(function () {
    var tags = $('#tags').select2().val().join(',');
    $('#{{ form.tags.vars.id }}').val(tags);
});
```